# Facebook developer setup register iOS

Tags: facebook

facebook developer for iOS android free or cost money for setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to register in special way to become a developer. You can simply create application at facebook (look at vertical menu at the left side of your facebook page - "Manage Apps"). After creating app at facebook, in menu item "Roles" you will see your profile in organizers category. Organizer has all roots as developer has.

Comment: Thanks what about the ads?

Comment: To find more info about ads, you should check this page https://www.facebook.com/business/products/ads